# Solve the PDE by factoring

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do you solve this PDE?
$$u_{tt}-5u_{xt}-36u_{xx}=0$$

I have factored it to:

$$\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} - 9\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) \left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} + 4\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)u=0$$

Then I separate the two to get:

$\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} - 9\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)u_1=0$

$\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} + 4\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)u_2=0$

I think I am supposed to integrate these after? (Please correct me if I am wrong). If so, I am not sure how to integrate them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You factored incorrectly, it should be 
$$
(\partial_t+9\partial_x)(\partial_t-4\partial_x)u=0
$$
This factorizations suggests the change of variables 
$$
\xi=x-9t\\
\eta=x+4t
$$
since under this change of variables, your pde becomes 
$$
u_{\xi\eta}=0
$$
(check this), now integrating twice yields
$$
u(\xi,\eta)=f(\xi)+g(\eta)\implies u(t,x)=f(x-9t)+g(x+4t)
$$
for arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Ah, I apologize. It was supposed to be a $-5u_{xt}$ and not $+5u_{xt}$

Comment: Well, can you see how to adapt the above to your problem?

Comment: I have one more question - I see that the signs have switched in the solution, why is that? Is it like the case when you find a root?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by find a root. The idea is to switch to a coordinate system that takes your mess of differential operators to a very simple one

Comment: I guess by finding a root I meant in a simple equation like $(x+2)(x-1)$ the roots would be $x=2$ and $x=1$. I am still unsure how the factorization results in the change of variables. Why $(\partial_t+9\partial_x)$ becomes $\xi=x-9t$ and why $(\partial_t-4\partial_x)u=0$ becomes $\eta=x+4t$?

Comment: @KBG did you check to see that under the change of variables your pde becomes the particularly simple one I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Those two are known as (linear) transport equations (with constant coefficients) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation

the solution to these is $u_1(x,t) = u_1^0(x+9t)$ for the first and an analogous form for the other one.
Now who is this $u^0_1$ I mentioned? You should be getting that from the starting data of you original PDE, without these boundary values the PDE doesn't infact make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Note that both PDEs in $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ are linear transport equations with constant coefficients. Thus, the first equation has the solution
$$
u_{1}(t,x)=f(x+9t)
$$
and analogously for $u_{2}$
$$
u_{2}(t,x)=g(x-4t)
$$
when $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are sufficiently smooth functions and would usually represent initial data.